# Looping through isEmpty

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

It can only detect the first condition, anything at if else wont work. The xpath is correct. If i do it without loop it will work. Anything what i did wrong here?

```
$pricediscount = "";
$chinesename ="";


if (empty($pricediscount)){
        $pricediscount = (@$xpath->query("//*[@id='J_PromoPrice']/div/strong/text()")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    }elseif(empty($pricediscount)){
        $pricediscount = (@$xpath->query("//*[@id='J_StrPrice']/em[2]")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    }elseif(empty($pricediscount)){
        $pricediscount = (@$xpath->query("//*[@id='J_PromoBox']/strong")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    }elseif(empty($pricediscount)){
        $pricediscount = (@$xpath->query("//*[@id='J_StrPrice']")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    }else{
        $pricediscount = "NA";
    }
```

Comment: Well, you're testing the same condition 3 times... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: If the first else if is empty, go next else if

Comment: If the first is empty all others are empty too, you're testing the same thing over and over... I don't understand what's your logic.

Comment: if first xpath query dont work, try next. if it has something it will update $pricediscount with something. So if there is somethign it's not empty, then stop

Comment: "//*[@id='J_StrPrice']" *************** both are different ************
 @$xpath->query("//*[@id='J_PromoBox']/strong"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ever only run the first `if` statement because it will always be true and therefore the `else` blocks will not be evaluated. Try changing the `elseif` and `else` statements to `if`.